# Get selected views rows in custom bulk webform operation

Tags: 8, views, webforms

I created a custom module for bulk update of specific field of webform submissions. However before the action is executed I need to retrieve which rows are selected. I created my action file and I inserted a hook_form_alter in my module where I print the $form_state but I do not see the values. Ideally I would need the selected rows inside my execute function but also any other way is welcomed. I paste below the code so far:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\webformbulk\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\Core\Action\ActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Push term in front.
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "approve_submission",
 *   label = @Translation("Mark submissions as approved"),
 *   type = "webform_submission"
 * )
 */
class ApproveSubmission extends ActionBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute($entity = NULL) {
    /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface  $entity */

    $init_hours = $entity->getElementData('hours_sep');

    $rows = count($init_hours);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
      $hours['hour_status'] = 'Approved';
      // If ()
      $init_hours[$i]['hour_status'] = 'Approved';
    }

    $entity->setElementData('hours_sep', $init_hours)->save();

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($object, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
    /** @var \Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface $object */
    $result = $object->locked->access('edit', $account, TRUE)
      ->andIf($object->access('update', $account, TRUE));

    return $return_as_object ? $result : $result->isAllowed();
  }

}
```

**webformbulk.module:**

```
/**
 *
 */
function webformbulk_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {

    // Check for bulk form id.
    case 'views_form_parliament_bookings_page_1':
      $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'webformbulk_form_submit';
      break;

  }

}

/**
 *
 */
function webformbulk_form_submit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  kint($form_state);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you need the selected rows for? Because you normally have everything in an `executeMultiple` function while the `execute` function only calls `$this->executeMultiple([$entity])`. Inside `executeMultiple` then you have all selected rows. Look at https://git.drupalcode.org/project/vbo_export/-/blob/8.x-3.x/src/Plugin/Action/VboExportBase.php which basically does exactly that.

Comment: My problem is that due to project requirements I have in every submission 3 different values of a composite webform element and in views I "break" every submission in 3 different rows for every composite element value with same entity_id. Consequently, when I select one row for updating a composite value, all 3 composite values are updated